# Jupyter stop working. Bag report: Bad file descriptor

Tags: cmd, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3, jupyter-irkernel

I try to use local jupyter notebook
To start i use cmd (win 10, 64 bit), it give me URLs, then i try to create NEW notebook.
But i see that Kernel have long beasy (do not stop) and after that i get pop-up in cmd - saying that "Bad file descriptor":

```
C:\Users\Стася>jupyter notebook
[I 2023-02-22 09:43:28.135 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 2023-02-22 09:43:28.135 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 09:43:28.155 NotebookApp] The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
[I 09:43:28.159 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Стася
[I 09:43:28.159 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.4.12 is running at:
[I 09:43:28.160 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8889/?token=16157ff4e8748f17468e22cb013a9b79f39f8404de936eff
[I 09:43:28.160 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=16157ff4e8748f17468e22cb013a9b79f39f8404de936eff
[I 09:43:28.160 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 09:43:28.292 NotebookApp]

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8F/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-5456-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8889/?token=16157ff4e8748f17468e22cb013a9b79f39f8404de936eff
     or http://127.0.0.1:8889/?token=16157ff4e8748f17468e22cb013a9b79f39f8404de936eff
[I 09:43:50.904 NotebookApp] 302 GET /?token=16157ff4e8748f17468e22cb013a9b79f39f8404de936eff (::1) 1.760000ms
[I 09:44:10.038 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
Bad file descriptor (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Bad file descriptor (C:\ci\zeromq_1616055400030\work\src\epoll.cpp:100)
```

i do not know how to resolve this issue...

I tried to find a similar problem on the internet, but I didn't find it.
Is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 0):

First you can;

```
pip unistall jupyter notebook
```

and then:

```
pip install jupyter notebook
pip install pyzmq==19.0.2
```